# Calculating and storing user's height using Swift, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, swift

I am an app where users can search for other users within a specified height range.  In Swift I have a UIPickerView with the following values:

```
seekingminHeightdata = ["Under 4'","4'1","4'2","4'3","4'4","4'5","4'6","4'7","4'8","4'9","4'10","4'11","5'","5'1","5'2","5'3","5'4","5'5","5'6","5'7","5'8","5'9","5'10","5'11","6'","6'1","6'2","6'3","6'4","6'5","6'6","6'7","6'8","6'9","6'10","6'11","7'","Above 7'"]
```

Once a user makes a selection that value is passed to a php file and later stored in the MySQL database.  My problem is I have to run a search on this field that would be something like this:

```
select * from users WHERE minheight < $minheight and maxheight >= $maxheight
```

I don't know how to perform the search with the ' in the values.  I know if I convert it to inches it will simplify what I want to do, but with the special characters in Swift UIPickerView I'm stumped.  Any help?

Comment: As a side note, keep in mind that most of the world will want to see the picker view values in cm (centimeters), not feet/inches.

Comment: Our initial rollout is to the US, once we incorporate other countries we'll incorporate cm.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a procedure and use it to compare two values. Here is an example that shows you can split a string using `'` character and compare 2 parts of it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING(str VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
SELECT @a1:= SPLIT_STRING("4'1", "'", 1);
SELECT @a2:= SPLIT_STRING("4'1", "'", 2);
SELECT @b1:= SPLIT_STRING("3'2", "'", 1);
SELECT @b1:= SPLIT_STRING("3'2", "'", 2);

SELECT @a1 > @b1;
SELECT @a2 > @b2;
```

You can use this procedure in your code and it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the value shown in a picker view from the value sent to your PHP script. As you stated, all of the calculations will be much simpler on the PHP side if you use inches (or centimeters or any other single unit value).

You also need to consider that most locales are metric and you should show users heights in centimeters, not feet/inches.

I suggest you keep an array of numbers, say in inches, from 48 to 84. Use that as your data. Then for display in the picker view you can convert that number to an appropriate display string such as feet/inches or cm.

When the user picks a row in the picker, you use the index to get the number from the array and pass that number to the PHP script where is can easily compare the numbers.

Comment: Thanks maddy.  Where I'm stuck is paragraph 3, I'm not sure how to show that conversion back to feet/inches.

Comment: `let feet = number / 12; let inches = number % 12; let str = "\(feet)'\(inches)\""`. This assumes `number` is an `Int` in total inches.

Comment: Write a function that takes an integer representing inches and have it return a string that can be used in the picker.